# How to cater HTTP and HTTPS requests on a website?

Tags: javascript, php, ssl

I have a videojs player in which I will load interactive elements like images/gmaps etc. 
The most important is images.
To make the player secure, I am planning add a SSL certficate but the images coming on the player can be from http or https.
How do I handle this?

Comment: Just  try it first. I believe some browsers will block mixed insecure content, although the user can choose to enable it.

Comment: I do not want to give the user a message where he feels that the content is insecure.

Comment: Are the images and maps on the same domain or a different one? If they are on the same domain, just load them relative to the site root as normal.

Comment: They are not on the same domain.

Comment: just place `//` infront of URL without `http` and `https`, and will work

Comment: After adding // code will work but if you launch .html file directly into browser it won't work you will have to load file through a web-server i.e. Apache or IIS @RiteshKsheersagar

Answer (score 1):

just place the link and leave rest on `Server` that either to put `HTTPS` or `HTTP`

do something like this

```
<img src = "//www.website.com/image_path_goes_here">
```

or for `a` tag

```
<a href = "/your_path">Click To Load</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't and load insecure content over a secure connection.  The // trick is only going to work if the images are available  over https.

One thing you could do is use a server side script with cURL to temporarily host the images you want, or to send them to the browser in an encoded format over https